# My Instagram Is Compromised Despite Security Measures

Tags: instagram

Two days ago, my Instagram posted some obvious scam photo about Ray Bans on my account. When I found out, I took the picture down. I changed my passwords on Facebook, Instagram and my two email accounts (All passwords rated strong by Google; the previous password was also strong). I also added two factor authentication on Instagram. You'd think this would do the trick, but today the same photo was posted on my Instagram. What can I do? Should I just start new accounts for email and social media? There's no record of any sign-ins on other devices. Google shows no suspicious activity. I feel I'm dealing with a dangerous foe. The only place I can think of this coming from is my Microsoft email. I opened a message from a friend that looked suspicious on Outlook, but I didn't enter any passwords or click any links.

Comment: It sounds like you've given access to your Instagram account to a rogue program. Check to see what apps have access to post on your account.

Comment: Thanks, but under authorized applications on Instagram it says "You have not authorized any applications to use your Instagram account."

I've deleted my Microsoft email and removed it as a recovery for my gmail (controls Instagram and Facebook) and changed all my passwords again. Hopefully that takes care of the problem.

Comment: The above unfortunately did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited info your provided it sounds like your device itself is compromised and keylogged (that or some shadow program has access to post on your insta through an API). Have you tried resetting all passwords on a secure device, then not logging in with the potentially compromised device for a few days to see if it still occurs?